# salesforce, editing static resources

Tags: css, salesforce

I am modifying in the pre-deployment sandbox.

After uploading the static resource for my visualforce page the css appears not to exist, it doesn't render at all.

I downloaded the static resource, made my css changes and then edited the static resource and uploaded my zipped folder.

Any idea why?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it!

It was when zipping the file: css and image folders need to be in the root directory of your zip file.

Comment: It could be in subdirectory in your zip file you just need to specify it when including that resource.